# Python loop to check rows in a column is null then replace

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to get a Non null value for the LastName, but I am receiving an error. How can I resolve this? p.s I have 20 millions rows.

dataframe:

```
FirstName   Middle  LastName
Tom          Ju     NaN
Kity         NaN    Rob
```

my attemp:

```
for row in df:
    if row['LastName'].isnull() == True:
        row['real_lastName'] =  row['Middle']
    else:
        row['real_lastName'] =  row['LastName']
```

i have the following error

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Don't iterate through your dataframe.

Comment: You have 'Middle' in the dataframe and 'middle' in the code sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['real_lastName'] = np.where(df['LastName'].isnull(), df['Middle'], df['LastName'] )

print (df)
  FirstName Middle LastName real_lastName
0       Tom     Ju      NaN            Ju
1      Kity    NaN      Rob           Rob
```

Another possible solution is use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) or [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df['real_lastName'] = df['LastName'].fillna(df['Middle'])

df['real_lastName'] = df['LastName'].combine_first(df['Middle'])
```

Performance is similar:

```
#[200000 rows x 4 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)
```

```
In [41]: %timeit df['real_lastName'] = np.where(df['LastName'].isnull(), df['Middle'], df['LastName'] )
13.3 ms ± 51.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [42]: %timeit df['real_lastName'] = df['LastName'].fillna(df['Middle'])
16.2 ms ± 58.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [43]: %timeit df['real_lastName'] = df['LastName'].combine_first(df['Middle'])
13 ms ± 100 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: you're a master

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
df["real_lastName"] = df['middle'].replace(np.NaN, '') + df['last_name'].replace(np.NaN, '')
```